# how to center dynamic div's with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a LOOP that places div's that contain images.
The idea is to place in each row 3 images,
I don't know how many images the user will insert.
but i do know that a the images/div's needs to be centered(!) inside the bootstrap grid.
like that:

---

_ _

I tried using list but with no success.
Thanks...

Comment: the example i tried to post wasn't shown very successfully.
I meant that if the loop brings 5 images, i need to place 3 centered divs on the first row and the remaining 2 will be placed on the second row but CENTERED!

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know this can't be done using default Bootstrap but no worries, you just need to add this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-centered"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-centered"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-centered"></div>
    </div>
</div>


/* centered columns styles */
.row-centered {
    text-align:center;
}
.col-centered {
    display:inline-block;
    float:none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align:left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right:-4px;
}
```

See more [here](http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns)

Answer (score -1):

you can play with "col-md-X" and "col-md-offset", the first one tell you the div's space and the second one the space in the left.